# Error al generar un archivo excel con node Js y mongo db

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, axios

Deseo generar un archivo excel con Node js, Express y Vue. la informacion sera sacada de un API. La base de datos esta sacada de una tabla creada en mongoDB
La libreria utilizada para generar el archivo excel es xlsx de javascript
Agradeceria cualquier ayuda

Archivo que el modelo de la tabla categorias

```
    import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const categoriaSchema = new Schema({
  nombre: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  descripcion: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  estado: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  eliminar: {
    type: String,
    default: "1"
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

const Categoria = mongoose.model("categoria", categoriaSchema);

export default Categoria;
```

Metodo de la Api, para traer toda la información:

```
    list: async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let valor = req.query.valor;
        const reg = await models.Categoria.find({
                $or: [{
                    'nombre': new RegExp(valor, 'i')
                }, {
                    'descripcion': new RegExp(valor, 'i')
                }]
            }, {
                createdAt: 0
            })
            .sort({
                'createdAt': 1
            });
        res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Ocurrió un error'
        });
        next(e);
    }
},
```

Informacion traida en formato JSON

```
[
{
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": "1",
    "_id": "5e04e9cafb04bf02cc8d78b3",
    "nombre": "Dama y vagabundo",
    "descripcion": "Ficcion",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": "1",
    "_id": "5e04e9fbfb04bf02cc8d78b4",
    "nombre": "Twisster",
    "descripcion": "Accion ",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": "1",
    "_id": "5e04ea0bfb04bf02cc8d78b5",
    "nombre": "Hacker",
    "descripcion": "Informatica",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": "1",
    "_id": "5e04ea27fb04bf02cc8d78b6",
    "nombre": "Bobinas",
    "descripcion": "Desconosido",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": "1",
    "_id": "5e0f6ba5bd91d725a434efab",
    "nombre": "Ciudad de dios",
    "descripcion": "Drama/social",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "estado": 1,
    "eliminar": "1",
    "_id": "5e308b34b7f36539dca0e907",
    "nombre": "Assasins Creed",
    "descripcion": "Fantasia",
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

Metodo el cual cargo la informacion:

```
    listar() {
  let me = this;
  let header = { Token: this.$store.state.token };
  let configuracion = { headers: header };
  axios
    .get("categoria/list", configuracion)
    .then(function(response) {
      me.categorias = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Este metodo cargara la informacion consultada a la API en formato JSON

A continuacion el metodo que genera el archivo excel.

```
   generarExcel() {
  this.categorias;
  let data = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(categorias);
  const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const filename = "Categorias";
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, data, filename);
  XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${filename}.xlsx`);
},
```

Deseo generar un archivo excel con los datos anteriormente mensionados y solo aparece el siguiente error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: categorias is not defined"
```

el cual ya se encuentra definido el arreglo  "categorias" para que almacene la informacion.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Por favor podrías explicar cuál es el problema específico? Copiaste todo el código, bien. Pero no aclaras cuál es el error (si acaso lo hay), cuál es el comportamiento deseado y cuál el obtenido. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo editare